# How does Eclipse determine whether a project can be added to a Java EE server?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I think images will better illustrate my problem. I have a Java project in Eclipse and am unable to add it to internal GlassFish. What must I do to for Eclipse to let me do this?

[image: Eclipse Java project]

[image: Desired action]

[image: Fails]

Comment: Is your project a web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Go to project Properties -> Project Facets. Click Convert to faceted form. A list of facets will appear. Check the Dynamic Web Module facet. Click Apply.

While still in project properties, go to Deployment Assembly. Delete the WebContent entry. Add a new entry, select the src/main/webapp directory. Click finish. It will deploy this directory to /.

That's it! Working like a charm for me!